# Matlab matrix Vs Python arange

Tags: python, numpy

Hi i am trying to convert a Matlab code in Python but when i convert  into Python it gives wrong length 
Matlab Code

```
a=N_bits/4+1;
T=20e-3;
Fc=8/T
dt=1/8/Fc;
t=dt:dt:a*T;
length(t)
```

Output:

```
1664
```

Python Code

```
N_bits=1e2
a=int((N_bits/4)+1)
T=20e-3
Fc=8/T
dt=(1/8)/Fc
t=arange(dt,(a*T),dt)
print(len(t))
```

Output:

```
1663
```

Comment: What is the value of `Fc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arange's stop (the second argument) is excluded in output.

```
>>> arange(0, 10, 2)
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
>>> len(_)
5
```

According to arange docstring:

> arange([start,] stop[, step,], dtype=None)
>
> ...
>
> Values are generated within the half-open interval `[start, stop)`

To get same result with matlab, adjust stop (the second argument):

```
arange(dt, (a*T)+dt, dt)
```

Comment: @marriamnayyer, Express thanks by accepting the answer and upvote. ;)